MINUS operator not working with CLOB type column
I'm  working in Oracle database and getting

ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB

error while using MINUS operator with a column of CLOB datatype.
Following is the query in which I'm getting the error:
SELECT  COMPONENT_ITEM, COMPONENT_REF_DES, QUANTITY
FROM M_ITEM2_CTE

MINUS

SELECT  COMPONENT_ITEM, COMPONENT_REF_DES, QUANTITY
FROM M_ITEM1_CTE

COMPONENT_REF_DES is the CLOB type column
I've tried NOT IN condition as well but same error, is there any alternative for MINUS operator while comparing CLOB datatypes?

The documentation shows restriction on set operators (like minus) which include "The set operators are not valid on columns of type BLOB, CLOB, BFILE, VARRAY, or nested table." Do you need to compare the entire CLOB value, or would the first 4000 characters be enough for what you're doing? Or if those are always actually the same (so component_item is a key), can you minus without that and get the value afterwards?

You cannot do a sort on a LOB. If you want to compare LOB values, you'll have to join the two rows together and use dbms_lob.compare

Rather than using set operators like MINUS (which require sorts, and you cannot sort a LOB), do an outer join and compare the LOBs with the dbms_lob.compare function:
SELECT i2.COMPONENT_ITEM, i2.COMPONENT_REF_DES, i2.QUANTITY
  FROM M_ITEM2_CTE i2,
       M_ITEM1_CTE i1
 WHERE i2.component_item = i1.component_item(+)
   AND NOT (i1.quantity = i2.quantity AND
            ((i1.component_ref_des IS NULL AND i2.component_ref_des IS NULL) 
             OR NVL(dbms_lob.compare(i1.component_ref_des,i2.component_ref_des),1) = 0
            )
           )

